# Create n number of variables where n is an argument

Tags: c

I have a C program that takes a command line argument n that can be 1 - 10. Based on that number, I need to create n distinct variables (eg. test(n), test(n+1), ...). Is there a certain way I can do this?

Since my range is small, I was thinking of doing an if or a switch statement on n, but that seems like a tedious way to do it.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Create argv[1] number of variables
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Errmm.. an array, maybe?

Comment: You can't really create variables on the fly.  You can create an array, though.

Comment: If VLA is supported, use an array; otherwise use a pointer

Comment: No, `calloc` it initialize the array elements to `0` for you. (preventing potential for attempted read from uninitialized space) `:p`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ..and always requires more cycles which may, or may not, be important.

Comment: Granted, but so far, I haven't run into a sizable performance difference between the two. (so far)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array, and convert the argument to `int` using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Program needs an int argument!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (n < 1 || n > 10)
    {
        printf("The argument must be in the range 1-10!\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int test[n];
    // use test...
    return 0;
}
```

This creates an `int` array with `argv[1]` elements, *if* the program is executed with at least one argument, and the first argument is within the range [1, 10]. If the first argument is not in the range of an `int` i.e. [`INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`], the program will cause undefined behavior.

Without VLA (variable-length array) support, you can use a dynamic array:

```
int* test = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Or you can simply make an array of size 10 and only use the first `n` elements of that array.

Comment: not every compiler likes this code. because the argument is not fixed.

Comment: Note that `argv[1]` is going to be a large, non-integer value - it won't compile.  You might get away with `int test[atoi(argv[1])];`.  Of course, it would be a good idea to check that `argv[1]` is not a null pointer before doing this, and the return from `atoi()` should be larger than zero and not so big that the stack overflows.

Comment: It does?  This works?  Surely, this requires dynamic alllocation?

Comment: still gcc may like this, but not every compiler will allow this.

Comment: argv[1] is a null-terminated char array.  I'm pretty sure that the OP did not wish to use that as an array size.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: This is valid C99 code. It's called a [Variable Length Array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays). If the poster can't use a language that was finalized 16 years ago, they need to specify it.

Comment: Or w/o VLA:  `int * test = malloc( atoi(argv[i]) * sizeof int )`

Comment: Since the OP knows the max value and it is small, `int vars[10];` is a much more portable and viable solution.  It allows argument checking where the C99 solution will likely invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MartinJames: It's passed to `atoi()`

Comment: @Bill, still this does not compile on every compiler. where did the op state that it is C99 ? I am not downvoting but this is something to be aware of.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: Should I only support K&R C? Is C89 acceptable? Why not the version of the language that was standardized 16 years ago? Why not the version that was standardized 4 years ago?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: But either way, I encourage you to make an additional answer if you feel that this one is not sufficient.

Comment: @Bill, it is based on experience that I say this, I have to support code that needs to compile using several versions of compilers and some don't support this, and these are modern compilers for embedded processors. It is just worth mentioning that this does not compile with every compiler. And again, I did not downvote.

Answer (score 2):

A straight forward dynamic allocation of the array is another acceptable way to approach the problem. For a small number of inputs in a known range, static allocation is fine, but when flexibility is needed, allocating dynamically, provides a way to grow the array as necessary and is generally safer from a portability standpoint that some of the other options. Here is a quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXELE 10

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    /* test for required input */
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.  usage: %s int (no. of array elements)\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* convert input to numeric form */
    size_t nelements = atoi (argv[1]);
    size_t i = 0;

    /* test values for 1 - 10 */
    if ( nelements < 1 || nelements > MAXELE ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: input not within 1 - %d.\n", MAXELE);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate nelements int for array & initialize to 0 */
    int *array = calloc (nelements , sizeof *array);

    /* test allocation succeeded, if not exit */
    if (!array) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* fill array with some numbers */
    for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
        array[i] = (i + 2) * i;

    /* print array */
    for (i = 0; i < nelements; i++)
        printf (" array[%2zu]  %d\n", i, array[i]);

    /* free memory allocated to array */
    if (array) free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/nintarray 10
 array[ 0]  0
 array[ 1]  3
 array[ 2]  8
 array[ 3]  15
 array[ 4]  24
 array[ 5]  35
 array[ 6]  48
 array[ 7]  63
 array[ 8]  80
 array[ 9]  99
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of taking questions verbatim: This solution actually allocates N variables on the stack in a recursion, not only an array with N items. You should not do this in a serious context:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct vars {
    struct vars *previous;
    int value;
} vars_t;

int run_main(vars_t *variables)
{
    vars_t *var;
    for (var = variables; var; var = var->previous) {
        printf("%p = %d\n", (void *) var, var->value);
    }
    return 0;
}

int alloc_vars(int n, vars_t *previous)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return run_main(previous);
    }

    vars_t current;
    current.previous = previous;
    current.value = n;
    return alloc_vars(n-1, &current);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    char *err_pos = NULL;
    long n = strtol(argv[1], &err_pos, 10);
    if (err_pos == argv[1] || *err_pos || n < 0) {
        return 2;
    }

    return alloc_vars(n, NULL);
}
```

Comment: This takes it from a evil creative genius standpoint. That isn't something I would have thought of :)